# stepwise regression crashes loop when all variables are not significant

Tags: r, loops

I am trying to do a series of stepwise regressions using OLSRR on several columns of data as different Y variables and the same five columns of data as the potential X's.  My code works fine until I hit a Y for which all five X's are not significant.  Then the code crashes and does not continue to loop through the remaining columns of data.  I get the message:  Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) :
:2:0: unexpected end of input

Is there a fix for this?

````
```    
library(olsrr)

for (i in 7:26) {

  model<-lm(data=PFAS,PFAS[[i]]~SumPCBs+PCBratio+sumBDEs+BDEratio+Hg)
  FWDfit.p<-ols_step_forward_p(model,penter=0.05)
  print(names(PFAS)[i])
  print(FWDfit.p[["model"]][["coefficients"]])
  BWDfit.p<-ols_step_backward_p(model,penter=0.05)
  print(BWDfit.p[["model"]][["coefficients"]])
  }
```
````

Comment: try to re-edit the problem to be more obvious

Answer (score 1):

I think Gregor is right. I'm going to take a guess that this error is being thrown by `ols_step_backward_p` in situations where the results of the backward elimination produce no significant results. If that guess is correct then just test for the length of those coefficients being greater than 1 and supply an alternate message:

```
for (i in 7:26) {

  model<-lm(data=PFAS,PFAS[[i]]~SumPCBs+PCBratio+sumBDEs+BDEratio+Hg)

    FWDfit.p<-ols_step_forward_p(model,penter=0.05)
    print(names(PFAS)[i])
    print(FWDfit.p[["model"]][["coefficients"]])
    BWDfit.p<-ols_step_backward_p(model,penter=0.05)
    if( length( coef(BWDfit.p) > 1) {
       print(BWDfit.p[["model"]][["coefficients"]])
                                } else { 
       cat( i, " no vars sig\n") }
  }
```

Comment: Quite right. Editing. How on earth did you end up in Traverse City? (I grew up there.)

Comment: My wife grew up there too :)

Comment: Ah, took a minute to recognize you with the new picture and username. Good to see you!

Comment: The complete error message is: Error in parse(text = x, keep.source = FALSE) : 
  <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: PFAS[[i]] ~

Comment: @PCDB11 In cases where the question involves a little known package, I think it's the responsibility of the questioner to provide a [MCVE]. That's the StackOverFlow Way. It doesn't have to be the original data; it could be a much smaller example built with 2 columns for the LHS and 2 or 3 columns for the RHS.

Comment: Thanks for being patient with me.  Part of the problem is that (length(coef(model)) is always 6.  Here is my data: